# To find radius of circle inscribed ∆ABC where for chosen points K,L,M at middle of ∆, distance sides are (4,2,10), (1,11,3) and (2,13,1)

Tags: geometry

**In the middle of triangle ABC, three points K, L, M are chosen so that the distances from point K to the sides of the triangle are equal to 4 cm, 2 cm and 10 cm, from point L, respectively, to 1 cm, 11 cm and 3 cm, from point M, respectively – 2 cm, 13 cm and 1 cm**. ***Find the radius of the circle inscribed in the triangle ABC***

Comment: Please don't [re-post questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4800965/446262).